# ¿Para que sirven los modelos en Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Disculpen mi ignorancia. Yo creo los modelos de la siguiente manera:

```
php artisan make:model Marcas -m
```

Y el modelo lo dejo tal cual se crea:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Marcas extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Modifico las migraciones asi:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateMarcasTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('marcas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->string('descripcion');
            $table->boolean('status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('marcas');
    }
}
```

Manipulo todas las funciones desde el controlador que lo creo así:

```
php artisan make:controller MarcasController --resource
```

Y lo modifico hasta quedar asi:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Closure;
use Auth;
use Session;
use Redirect;
use DB;
use PDO;
use Validator;
use Response;
use Datatables;
use Debugbar;
use Alert;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Marcas;

class MarcasController extends Controller
{
    protected $auth;
    public function __construct(Guard $auth){
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('ruta:Marcas');
        $this->middleware('funciones:Marcas,crear',['only'=>['crear']]);
        $this->middleware('funciones:Marcas,editar',['only'=>['editar']]);
        $this->middleware('funciones:Marcas,eliminar',['only'=>['eliminar']]);
        $this->middleware('funciones:Marcas,estado',['only'=>['estado']]);
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(){
        return view('marcas.index');
    }

    public function tabla(Request $request){
        try{
            $sql = Marcas::select(array('id', 'nombre', 'descripcion', 'status'));
            return Datatables::of($sql)
            ->addColumn('action', ' Editar  Eliminar')
            ->addColumn('estado', 'activo')
            ->filter(function ($query) use ($request) {
                if ($request->has('campo')) {
                    $query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT( nombre, ' ', descripcion )"), 'ilike', "%{$request->get('campo')}%");
                }
                if ($request->has('status')) {
                    $query->where('status', '=', "{$request->get('status')}");
                }
            })
            ->make();
        }catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
            $array = array(
                'mensaje' => $e->getMessage(),
                'codigo' => $e->getCode(),
                'sql' => $e->getSql(),
                'bindings' => $e->getBindings(),
            );
            return Response::json(array('ErrorSql' => $array));
        }
    }

    public function crear(Request $req) {
        $rules = array(
            'nombre' =>  'required|unique:cargos|min:5|max:30',
        );
        $validator = Validator::make ( Input::all (), $rules );
        if ($validator->fails()){
            return Response::json(array('errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()));
        }else{
            try{
                $cargos = new Marcas();
                $cargos->nombre = $req->nombre;
                $cargos->status = 't';
                $cargos->save();
                return Response::json(array('correcto' => $cargos->toArray()));
            }catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
                $array = array(
                    'mensaje' => $e->getMessage(),
                    'codigo' => $e->getCode(),
                    'sql' => $e->getSql(),
                    'bindings' => $e->getBindings(),
                );
                return Response::json(array('ErrorSql' => $array));
            }
        }
    }

    public function editar(Request $req){
        $rules = array(
            'nombre' =>  'required|min:5|max:30',
        );
        $validator = Validator::make ( Input::all (), $rules );
        if ($validator->fails()){
            return Response::json(array('errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()));
        }else{
            try{
                if(Marcas::where('nombre', 'ilike', $req->nombre)->where('id', '', $req->id)->exists()){
                    return Response::json(array('encontrado' => 'nombre ya ha sido registrado'));
                }else{
                    $cargos = Marcas::find ($req->id);
                    $cargos->nombre = $req->nombre;
                    $cargos->save();
                    return Response::json(array('correcto' => $cargos->toArray()));
                }
            }catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
                $array = array(
                    'mensaje' => $e->getMessage(),
                    'sql' => $e->getSql(),
                    'bindings' => $e->getBindings(),
                );
                return Response::json(array('ErrorSql' => $array));
            }
        }
    }

    public function eliminar(Request $req){
        try{
            Marcas::find($req->id)->delete();
                $array = array(
                    'mensaje' => 'todo bn',
                );
                return Response::json(array('correcto' => $array));
        }catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
            if($e->getCode()==23503){
                $array = array(
                    'mensaje' => $e->getMessage(),
                    'sql' => $e->getSql(),
                    'bindings' => $e->getBindings(),
                );
                return Response::json(array('ClaveForanea' => $array));
            }else{
                $array = array(
                    'mensaje' => $e->getMessage(),
                    'sql' => $e->getSql(),
                    'bindings' => $e->getBindings(),
                );
                return Response::json(array('ErrorSql' => $array));
            }
        }
    }
```

Segun leo en este articulo: [enlace](https://styde.net/aprende-a-usar-eloquent-el-orm-de-laravel/)
dice que alli definimos que campos podemos modificar, eliminar, etc.
Pero yo en los modelos de Laravel ni los toco y todo me anda bien.

Que hacen realmente los modelos en laravel.

Comment: ¿Conoces el patrón de diseño MVC?

Comment: @Naos algo, pero según entiendo en el MVC todas las consultas van en el modelo, aca veo que no lo requiere, porque simplemente llamas al modelo y ejecutas la funcion que lo hace, ¿o estoy mal? y tambien he leido que Laravel ya no es MVC y por eso vemos los modelos fuera de una carpeta que se llame Model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La respuesta a la pregunta la encuentras en el archivo: `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, analizando cada propiedad y cada método puedes hacerte la idea de para qué sirve un modelo y cuando tener uno o no para una tabla.

En general con un modelo en Laravel puedes:

- Establecer los parámetros de interacción con la tabla correspondiente en la base de datos (nombre, llaves, campos protegidos, etc.)
- Establecer las relaciones con otras tablas, para poder precargar dicha información como propiedad de cada modelo (tal vez la función más importante de todas, y la que más tiempo puede ahorrarnos)
- Realizar ciertas tareas simples y típicas como guardar, obtener todos los registros, borrar, etc.
- Aprovechar "Eager Loading", bastante útil en muchas situaciones
- Disparar eventos
- Manejar paginación

Entre tantas otras funciones que puedes ver en el archivo en mención.

Por cierto, las consultas complejas que necesites hacer a la base de datos no deberían ser realizadas ni desde un controlador (no es su responsabilidad) ni en el modelo, para esto puedes usar preferiblemente un repositorio.

Comment: gracias hermano :D

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, yo lo utilizo para manejar desde ese punto mi base de datos. Te daré un ejemplo con un Model y lo explicaré...

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableScopeHelpers;
use Carbon\Carbon;
class Articulo extends Model{
use Sluggable, SluggableScopeHelpers;

/**
 * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function sluggable()
{
    return [
        'slug' => [
            'source' => 'titulo'
        ]
    ];
}
 protected $table = 'articulos';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['titulo', 'contenido','slug','path','etiqueta','user_id','categoria_id'];

public function setPathAttribute($path){
    if(! empty($path)){
        $name = Carbon::now()->second.$path->getClientOriginalName();
        $this->attributes['path'] = $name;
        \Storage::disk('local')->put($name, \File::get($path));
    }
}



public function categoria(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Blog\Categoria');
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Blog\User');
}

public function scopeTitulo($query, $titulo){//Funcion para hacer una busqueda 
    if(trim($titulo) != ''){ //Funcion trim para eliminar los espacios
        $query->where(\DB::raw("titulo"),"LIKE","%$titulo%");
    }


}
}
```

En ese modelo tengo el `sluggable` Esta función es parte de un eloquent que me sirve para que a la hora de guardar algún post digamos y el titulo sea algo como "Este es mi primer post" el sluggable lo guarda en mi base de datos como "Este-es-mi-primer-post" y así trabaja de una forma mas limpia y mejor vista los link

La funcion `setPathAttribute` la uso para que al guardar las imagenes no se guarden con un nombre repetido

Las funciones `categoria` y `user` las estoy relacionando de alguna manera a este modelo o tabla `Articulo` y luego a la hora en mi controlador o en mi codigo HTML poder usar algo de mis relaciones entre tablas gracias a esto

y por ultimo el `scopeTitulo` esto es un simple buscador...

Todo esto esta dentro de mi Model y me ayuda a resolver muchas cosas dentro de mi Base de Datos.

Comment: y no es algo que se puede hacer desde un controlador? es algo q se debe hacer como tu lo haces? o es algo debatible?

Comment: Claro que es debatible, pero a lo que voy es a lo siguiente que esas funciones que están ahí se deben trabajar desde un Model, bueno es lo que yo tengo entendido, y hablo de todas, pero sería cuestion de intentar, pero las funciones de categoría y user si deben ir ahí y puedes buscar en documentación de Laravel.

Comment: esas funciones que trabajas en el Model las llamas? o ellas se ejecutan automáticamente cuando envías algo a la BD?

Comment: En la del Scope envias al buscador una función llamada "titulo" y el buscará dentro del Model algo que empiece con scope y que diga "scopeTitulo" y hará lo que le pidas y lo enviará a donde lo tenga que enviar.